# How to set the Preview mode of android studio?

Tags: android, settings, default, preview

[image]
My android studio screen is showing like this as shown below. Please tell me how can I set this on default mode? I have changed some settings accidently but now I don't understand where I did the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "File" menu in Android Studio and select "Manage IDE Settings".

Click on "Restore Default Settings".

In the confirmation dialog that appears, click "OK".

Wait for Android Studio to restart with default settings
This should reset your Android Studio to its default configuration.

If you have made any customizations to the settings or preferences, you will need to redo them after resetting to default.

Comment: My android screen is not showing any bar from which I select that option. Any shortcut key doesn't work. I have reinstall my android studio but issue does not resolved.